# TPS63060 enable pin driver

Tags: power-electronics, led-driver, enable

because I want to have PWM dimming LED, I have connected PWM signal to EN pin of TPS63060. I wonder is this correct? According to datasheet chip have soft-start so it shouldn't destroy LED. PWM signal have 180Hz frequency, LED is white 1W power.

Schema: [image]

Simulation: [image]
Green signal is output voltage, blue LED current and red one is EN signal. At start we can see one peak for around 330mA and after that signal is stabilizes to 300mA.

[TPS63060 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63060.pdf?ts=1606046278019&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Comment: Show the complete circuit proposal and include data sheet links for the chip and the LEDs.

Comment: This is circuit in LTspice : https://imgur.com/a/8JdX6px
This is datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63060.pdf?ts=1606046278019&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F
LED is white 1W and PWM signal for EN pin have 180Hz.

Comment: You can embed schematics into your question. Given that it is an LTSpice schematic, what does running a simulation tell you about LED current?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6gPduRN
Green signal is output voltage, blue LED current and red one is EN signal. At start we can see one peak for around 330mA and after that signal is stabilizes to 300mA.

Comment: You need to embed all of this information inside your question above. This isn't a forum, it's a Q and A site and people expect full details inside the question.

Comment: Already change it.

Comment: Images can be directly embedded - nobody wants to follow links when images can be directly displayed. All the relevant technical details in comments should be in the body of the question. I thought I was clear about that?

Comment: I corrected it, thanks for helpful comments

Comment: The minimum level of soft start current is 400 mA so if you are expecting this to have an effect then it won't because you are running your LED at 330 mA (i.e. below the SS current limit). I also see a discrepancy in the current produced; if you have a 1.66 ohm current sense resistor, the peak current to the LED should be no more than 300 mA and not 330 mA.

Comment: So maybe I should use this one to control LED ? https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP5030-D.PDF
It looks similar to the TPS63060 but producent describes EN/CTRL as pin which can handle PWM.